# PHP File upload not working

Tags: php, file-upload

For some reason file upload is not working for this `.ppt` file that I am trying to upload. I have tested it with another ppt file (approximately 250kb) and it worked fine... but this one is 10mb and the `$_FILE` array is empty when I echo it. Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?? I know my PHP file is right.

index.php:

```
<form action="http://localhost:80/phpconverter/upload.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"
            value="102400000" />
    Choose a file to upload:
    <input id="fileName" name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>

    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#"
        style="width:200px;height:500px;border:0px solid #fff;"> </iframe>
</form>
```

When checking if the file is empty or not (i.e. `empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"]`) I see that the file is empty, when I have in fact uploaded a file!!

Answer (score 5):

Your file is too big and exceeds the PHP file default limit which is 2MB.

You have to increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in either `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file.

Comment: memory_limit and post_max_size may also come into play here.

Comment: create another file and put only one line `phpinfo()` and see if the your change has been reflected

Answer (score 2):

> but this one is 10mb and the $_FILE array is empty when I echo it

The default PHP configuration places *either* a 2MB or 8MB limit on uploaded file sizes.

Please refer to the [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and the [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) configuration settings in your php.ini file.  `post_max_size` *must* be equal to or larger than `upload_max_filesize`.  These settings *can not* be changed at run-time.

Comment: Okay I have increased both post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 100M and it still doesn't work....

Comment: What does a `phpinfo()` call say the new settings are?